# Azure AI Search Text Split Skill Debug Session Error

Tags: azure, search, text, split, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to implement a Text Split cognitive skill in my AI enrichment pipeline.

My skillset is defined as follows:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://<redacted>/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"<redacted>\"",
  "name": "documentindexingskillset",
  "description": "",
  "skills": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.DocumentExtractionSkill",
      "name": "doc_extract_skill",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document",
      "parsingMode": "default",
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "file_data",
          "source": "/document/file_data"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "content",
          "targetName": "extracted_content"
        },
        {
          "name": "normalized_images",
          "targetName": "extracted_normalized_images"
        }
      ],
      "configuration": {
        "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages",
        "normalizedImageMaxWidth@odata.type": "#Int64",
        "normalizedImageMaxWidth": 2000,
        "normalizedImageMaxHeight@odata.type": "#Int64",
        "normalizedImageMaxHeight": 2000
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Vision.OcrSkill",
      "name": "doc_ocr_skill",
      "description": "Extracts text (plain and structured) from image.",
      "context": "/document/extracted_normalized_images/*",
      "textExtractionAlgorithm": null,
      "lineEnding": "Space",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "detectOrientation": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "image",
          "source": "/document/extracted_normalized_images/*"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "targetName": "imageText"
        },
        {
          "name": "layoutText",
          "targetName": "imageLayoutText"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.MergeSkill",
      "name": "doc_merge_skill",
      "description": "Create merged_text, which includes all the textual representation of each image inserted at the right location in the content field.",
      "context": "/document",
      "insertPreTag": " ",
      "insertPostTag": " ",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/extracted_content"
        },
        {
          "name": "itemsToInsert",
          "source": "/document/extracted_normalized_images/*/imageText"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "mergedText",
          "targetName": "mergedText"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.LanguageDetectionSkill",
      "name": "doc_language_detection",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document",
      "defaultCountryHint": "",
      "modelVersion": null,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/mergedText"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "languageCode",
          "targetName": "languageCode"
        },
        {
          "name": "languageName",
          "targetName": "languageName"
        },
        {
          "name": "score",
          "targetName": "score"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.SplitSkill",
      "name": "doc_text_split",
      "description": "",
      "context": "/document",
      "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
      "textSplitMode": "pages",
      "maximumPageLength": 1000,
      "pageOverlapLength": 100,
      "maximumPagesToTake": 0,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "source": "/document/mergedText"
        },
        {
          "name": "languageCode",
          "source": "/document/languageCode"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "textItems",
          "targetName": "mypages"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices",
    "description": null
  },
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

My indexer is defined as follows:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "<redacted>/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"<redacted>\"",
  "name": "cs-ai-uks-01-ixr-02",
  "description": null,
  "dataSourceName": "ds-cs-ai-uks-02-saaiuksstg01",
  "skillsetName": "documentindexingskillset",
  "targetIndexName": "cs-ai-uks-02-is-02",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": null,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": null,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages",
      "allowSkillsetToReadFileData": true
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/mypages",
      "targetFieldName": "Content"
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

And finally, my index is defined as follows:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "<redacted>/$metadata#indexes/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"<redacted>\"",
  "name": "cs-ai-uks-02-is-02",
  "defaultScoringProfile": null,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": true,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": null,
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Content",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "searchable": true,
      "filterable": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "facetable": false,
      "key": false,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
      "normalizer": null,
      "dimensions": null,
      "vectorSearchProfile": null,
      "synonymMaps": []
    }
  ],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "corsOptions": null,
  "suggesters": [],
  "analyzers": [],
  "normalizers": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "semantic": null,
  "vectorSearch": null
}
```

My AI Search Service is currently configured on a Basic pricing Tier (SKU: B).

I'm experiencing two issues:

1. When I run the indexer, it completes successfully, all the documents in my storage container are indexed, but the text is not being split. The "maximumPageLength" and "pageOverlapLength" parameters are set to 1000 and 100 respectively, but the text in the Content field of my indexed documents contains way more text than that. I would expect that the Content field contains roughly a 1000 characters according to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-textsplit)
2. When I try to configure a debug session I get the following error when saving the debug session:

**Failed to create debug session "new-debug-session", error: "InvalidSkillset: One or more skills are invalid. Details: Unexpected properties found on Skill. Parameters: Debug.Skillset"**

When I remove the Text Split skill from my skillset, I can save and run the debug session without problems.

I don't understand the "Unexpected properties found on Skill. Parameters: Debug.Skillset" message since there is no such parameter defined?

I'd appreciate any input and thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: OK, I've noticed that the problem seems to revolve around the "pageOverlapLength" parameter in the skillset so I've made sure to use the "2023-10-01-Preview" api version when creating both the skillset and the indexer using the Azure Search rest API, but I get the same error when creating a debug session and the text still isn't being split.

Comment: Update: The Text Split skill DOES split the text with the specified overlap. I just did not take into account the cardinality of Azure AI Search indexers, i.e: one document in your storage container is always indexed as one record into your Azure AI Search index. If you implement a text split skill, the content of your indexed document will be split into an array of strings, but that array will still be indexed as ONE record into the index.

Comment: Update: The problem with the debug session giving the "InvalidSkillset" error persists though, perhaps the debug session is still running an older API that does not support the "pageOverlapLength" parameter?